# How to copy variables from variable explorer (Spyder python 3.5) to clipboard

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, clipboard

Basically I want to copy multi dimensional arrays into EXCEL sheet.

If this is not possible, Atleast I should be able to export LIST from variable explorer in spyder.

I tried

`

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

array = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
         ['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
         ['a7', 'a8', 'a9'],
         ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']]
row = 0
for col, data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
workbook.close()
```

`
However, I couldnt copy string data which is stored as data.

Comment: `numpy.std` does not 'standardize' (whatever that means) the dataset. It computes the standard deviation. That is one value for a vector, that describes how similiar the different elements are.

Comment: Thats true only when we dont mwentions axis
`
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> np.std(a)
1.1180339887498949
>>> np.std(a, axis=0)
array([ 1.,  1.])
>>> np.std(a, axis=1)
array([ 0.5,  0.5])  `

Comment: Well, it is true also when mentioning axis. However, the `axis` value can be used to calculate the standard deviation for each row or each column separately. You still don't get the same matrix back, but an array of standard deviations.

Comment: @MachineLearningEnthusiast What is your definition of *standardized*?

Comment: Now I understood....I was assuming, Standardizing to making the dataset as gaussian

Comment: Hi How to accept an answer here...

Comment: Since there is no answer, only comments to your question, there is nothing to accept.

Answer (score 3):

Found turn around solution...

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=MyDataAsNumpyArray)

df.to_clipboard(excel=True)
```

Comment: To exclude headers and column names: `import pandas; df = pandas.DataFrame(mynparray); df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)`

Answer (score 0):

For single lists that are not multidimensional you can open the variable explorer, highlight the data (scrolling from top to bottom), and then copy (right click - select copy). If you simply copy the variable, you don't get a column, you get a string representation of the variable.